# Plugin compatibility issue in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a theme that does not seem to be completely compatible with a plugin in wordpress.

The plugin is called: DHVC Woocommerce products.

It seems to throw issues in javascript:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

script.js?ver=2.1.9:7 cannot call methods on isotope prior to initialization; attempted to call 'reLayout'

The issue seems to be with the find function amoung others:

```
    getSortData: {
                    menu_order: function ($elem) {
alert($elem);
                        return $elem.find('.product-name a ').text();
                    }
```

Does anyone have any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: yes, its loading the js file before jquery or not loading jquery at all. All new themes include jquery in the footer (mostly) if your file is in the header, its going to throw errors. BTW WP uses noconflict jquery so replace '$` with `jQuery` just in case $elem is not a valid object after correcting this.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I guess ill have to figure out where its loading the JQuery then...

Comment: script.js probably also need to set isotope as a dependency so script.js will load after isotope. Would need to see your theme's code that is enquing the scripts.